# AngularJS not working on express server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm currently learning AngularJS and trying some basic examples. I have installed Node and used npm to put express in the directory i'm using for my examples. I have been following a simple example to view a html file on a express server that I created, however the output is showing {{heading + message}}

(pictured below)
[view of page when loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSrvz.jpg)

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="firstApp">
<head>
    <title>First AngularJS App</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="first.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="first">
        <input type="text" ng-model="last">
        <button ng-click='updateMessage()'>Message</button>
        <hr>
        {{heading + message}}
    </div>

</body>
```

**first.js**

```
var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);

firstApp.controller('FirstController', function ($scope) {
$scope.first = 'Some';
$scope.last = 'One';
$scope.heading = 'Message: ';
$scope.updateMessage = function () {
    $scope.message = 'Hello ' + $scope.first + ' ' + $scope.last + '!';
};
});
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: you should return `$scope.message` in `updateMessage` method. may be it will work because code is right

Comment: The **very first thing** you need to do if you are going to develop javascript apps is to learn to use your browser console.  Chrome and Firefox both have excellent, built-in consoles.  If you turned on the console, went to the "Console" tab, and ensured "JS" was on, you'd guaranteed see an error, which will start getting you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to press F12 and check what if there are some errors in the console. I think it can not find your `first.js` script.
It probably should be something like `<script src="/public/first.js"></script>`.

In general the example from your question works:

```js
var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);

firstApp.controller('FirstController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.first = 'Some';
  $scope.last = 'One';
  $scope.heading = 'Message: ';
  $scope.updateMessage = function () {
    $scope.message = 'Hello ' + $scope.first + ' ' + $scope.last + '!';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="firstApp">
<head>
    <title>First AngularJS App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="first">
        <input type="text" ng-model="last">
        <button ng-click='updateMessage()'>Message</button>
        <hr>
        {{heading + message}}
    </div>

</body>
```

Note, that you even don't need the node.js to run this example. [Here is](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/quick-test/test.html) a standalone HTML which also works.

Comment: Thanks Boris there was a mix up with my file paths, rookie mistake! It all works fine now :)